# How to use WordPress GDPR Cookie Consent plugin for Google Analytics

Tags: wordpress, google-analytics, gdprconsentform

I add the **GDPR Cookie Consent plugin** in my **WordPress** application.
When the use disables non necessary cookies, the **Google Analytics** should be blocked otherwise enabled.
At the GDPR plugin I find two fields for that:

```
This script will be added to the page HEAD section if the above settings is enabled and user has give consent.
```

and

```
This script will be added right after the BODY section if the above settings is enabled and user has given consent.
```

There I can leave JavaScript code.
Than I find the Google support page: [developers.google.com/analytics/devguides/...disabling_cookies](https://developers.google.com/analytics/devguides/collection/analyticsjs/cookies-user-id#disabling_cookies)

But I cant get it together. This is to complicate for me. I know my GA Tracking ID.

**Which JavaScript code do I need to implement in which GDPR plugin field?**

Thanks a lot!

Answer (score 0):

You may please copy the Google Analytics tracking code from the analytics account as mentioned [here](https://support.google.com/analytics/answer/1008080?hl=en) and copy it to the head script section on the [cookie consent plugin](https://wordpress.org/plugins/cookie-law-info/) you mentioned.